# Close UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to close soon after a `UIViewController` call another. It should be simple, but I'm not succeeding. I am using the following method:

```
- (IBAction)bClose:(id)sender {

    iTest *test = [[iTest alloc] initWithNibName:@"iTest" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
    [test release];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That won't work as you are trying to dismiss a controller that still has a child-controller open. You should go back to the drawing board and find a proper way to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not simple. I have done something similar but instead I present the second in the first, then dismiss the first when the second wants to dismiss (dismissing both at the same time). To explain what I mean better:

1. main -> present controller1
2. controller1 -> present controller2
3. controller2 -> dismiss controller1

I'm sure there is a better solution to it though.

Something like this:

inside first controller:

```
UIViewController *c1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController: c1 animated:YES];
```

inside c1:

```
UIViewController *c2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
c2.c1 = self;
[self presentModalViewController: c2 animated:YES];
```

inside c2:

```
[c1 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Edited to add some code. I can't tell you if this works or not, but I think I did something like this. Don't have the code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

i also had to try something similar..but ran into much of the same problem..

**My solution was to initiate a timer with time 0.5 sec and then dismiss the view in the selector**

Worked for me.

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(close) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; - (void) close {[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];} - it still fails, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Check by breakpoint in the close method to confirm dismissModalview is being called.  If it is. Then change the delay to a more higher value. At some value.the view will be dismissed. This all depends how much the second view takes time to initiate itself

Comment: I think you have to dismiss before you present the new one, but I could be wrong.